# Using Dapper with SQLite, Query Method throws a null reference exception

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, orm, dapper

**Testing environment：**

-- Framework version: .NET 6

-- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, version: 6.0.6

-- Dapper, version: 2.0.123

**Q: When only one query is executed, there is no problem.  Problems occur when multiple concurrent queries are executed.**

**(Reference: When I write code in native ADO.NET instead of Dapper(conn.Query), there is no problem!)**

Here is a simple demo that can reproduce the problem very easily.

```
using System.Data;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

// SQLite db file
string connStr = $"Data Source={AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}test.db";

// SQLite connection (Share the singleton connection) 
using SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
 
bool existError = false;
while (true)
{
    if (existError == true)
    {
        break;
    }

    // Perform concurrent reads
    Parallel.For(0, 100, index =>
    {
        try
        {
            // Test SQL
            string sql_test = " select * from T_Account where AccountId='ab001' ";

            // Perform query data (May throw a null reference exception )
            var t = conn.Query(sql_test);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            existError = true;

            // Test output: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            Console.WriteLine($"Read error ({index}): {ex.Message}");
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}-------- split line --------");
}
```

**The whole project has been using Dapper, I want to know where the problem is, how should I solve it?**

Comment: You are using the same conenction in all queries, That's very bad practice. Create a new connection for each query.

Comment: @PalleDue It makes sense to share the same connection, at least to prevent multiple connections from concurrently operating on SQLite's own BUSY problem .

Comment: Also, this is not really the point, but why NULL reference errors occur.  But if I use the same process, just change Dapper(conn.query) to Ado.NET mode, it won't throw wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might think that it's a super good idea to reuse the connection, but it isn't. There already is a connection pool built-in to ADO, and it's far more efficient than anything we can come up with. I tried to run your code, obviously with another sqlite database and query, and on the 6th or 7th iteration I got the null reference exception. Then I changed your code like this:

```cs
// Perform concurrent reads
Parallel.For(0, 100, index =>
{
    try
    {
        // These two lines moved inside the loop
        using SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();

        // Test SQL
        string sql_test = " select * from T_Account where AccountId='ab001' ";

        // Perform query data (May throw a null reference exception )
        var t = conn.Query(sql_test);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        existError = true;

        // Test output: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        Console.WriteLine($"Read error ({index}): {ex.Message}");
    }
});
```

And the code can go on and on as expected. Best practice is to create the database connection in a using statement and have it disposed as soon as you are done with it.
Since I haven't seen your code with raw ADO.NET, I can't tell why that works.

Comment: Thank you. Here's the background on why connection pooling is not used here: The default connection pool has always been used, especially for Mysql and Sqlserver. However, I currently have an old desktop application that uses SQLite. The application currently performs a high number of concurrent operations, now there are more problems, such as DB locked and busy.. I looked up  materials and learned about the application scheme of SQLite singleton pattern.  But the current practice is still not very smooth. Maybe I need to implement a custom connection pool for a particular scenario.